# JavaScript: Merge multiple classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, dto, monorepo, class-validator

I want to combine multiple classes for reusability and consistency amongst backend and frontend. Something like:

```js
import {
  IsEmail,
  IsString,
  MaxLength,
  MinLength,
  validateSync
} from "class-validator";

class UserUsername {
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  @MaxLength(10)
  username!: string;
}

class UserEmail {
  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;
}

class UserPassword {
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(8)
  password!: string;
}

class UserSecret {
  @IsString()
  secret!: string;
}

class User /* extends UserEmail, UserUsername, UserSecret */ {}
class UserDto /* extends UserEmail, UserUsername, UserPassword */ {}

const userDto = new UserDto();

userDto.username = "noerror";
userDto.email = "error";
userDto.password = "error";

console.log(validateSync(userDto).toString());
```

Is something similar anyway possible?

**Note:** I do not mean types only like TypeScript's `&`. The main purpose is to reuse class validation.

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-heyrovsky-h3x9j?file=/src/index.ts)

## The Problem:

```js
export class User {
  @IsUUID()
  id!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  username!: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  secret!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  firstName!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  lastName!: string;

  @IsBoolean()
  isEmailVerified!: boolean;
}

export class UserDto {
  @IsUUID()
  id!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  username!: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;

  secret?: never;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  firstName!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  lastName!: string;

  @IsBoolean()
  isEmailVerified!: boolean;
}

export class SignUpUserDto {
  id?: never;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  username!: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;

  secret?: never;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  firstName!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  lastName!: string;

  isEmailVerified?: never;
}

export class UpdateUserDto {
  id?: never;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  username?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsEmail()
  email?: string;

  secret?: never;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  firstName?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsAlpha()
  lastName?: string;

  isEmailVerified?: never;
}

export class SignInUserDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username!: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  password!: string;
}
```

#### See how repetitive the code is?

Comment: depending the use case you may be able to extend a single base class and then have an `implements` statement for the multiple properties / declarations.

Comment: thank you @Jhecht. `implements` is a TypeScript thing, I want this to work on classes as well for class-validator to be able to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Filip Kaštovský who pointed me to this doc: [How Does A Mixin Work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#how-does-a-mixin-work)?

I got to solve it this way:

```js
import { IsString, IsUUID, MinLength, validateSync } from 'class-validator';

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export function WithUserId<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  class UserId extends Base {
    @IsUUID()
    id!: string;
  }

  return UserId;
}

export function WithUserUsername<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  class UserUsername extends Base {
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(3)
    username!: string;
  }

  return UserUsername;
}

export function WithUserSecret<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  class UserSecret extends Base {
    @IsString()
    secret!: string;
  }

  return UserSecret;
}

class User extends WithUserId(WithUserUsername(WithUserSecret(class {}))) {}

const user = new User();

user.id = "9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d";
user.username = "a";
user.secret = "a";

console.log(validateSync(user).toString());
```

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-heyrovsky-h3x9j?file=/src/final.ts)

**EDIT:**
I cloned [@nestjs/mapped-types](https://github.com/nestjs/mapped-types) and modified it to work in both the browser and nodejs. I wanted to publish it but I do not know a lot about publishing and whether it is actually going to work. It works fine in my set-up with Nx because I used [Nx to create the library](https://nx.dev/latest/react/workspace/library#nrwlworkspacelibrary).

Answer (score 1):

There is a really neat way of doing this using the [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern) pattern.

```
class UserDto {}
interface UserDto extends UserEmail, UserUsername, UserPassword {}
applyMixins(UserDto, [UserEmail, UserUsername, UserPassword]);

const userDto = new UserDto();

userDto.username = 'noerror';
userDto.email = 'error';
userDto.password = 'error';

console.log(validateSync(userDto).toString());
```

using this util:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
    constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
            Object.defineProperty(
                derivedCtor.prototype,
                name,
                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
                    Object.create(null)
            );
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did not work but I used the same documentation to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would make more sense(and solve the problem) this way:

> If you really need join three classes, you could try mixins: https://javascript.info/mixins

```js
class UserLogin {
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(3)
  @MaxLength(10)
  username!: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email!: string;
}

class UserPassword {
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(8)
  password!: string;
}

class UserSecret {
  @IsString()
  secret!: string;
}

class User extends UserSecret {
   /// Secret things here...
}

class UserDto extends UserPassword {
   /// Password things here...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can this achieve what you need?

```
Class User{
   userEmail: UserEmail;
   userUserName: UserUserName;
   userPassword: UserPassword;
}
```